# In spring boot application All the Tomcat threads goes into waiting state resulting into Tomcat being unresponsive

Tags: spring-boot, locking, deadlock, tomcat8, serversocket

I am using spring boot. I configured port 8080 for http calls. After some time Tomcat becomes unresponsive. Below is the Jstack of a thread.

> http-nio-8080-exec-95" #1063 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f0d8c074000 nid=0xf255 waiting on condition [0x00007f0d49f2f000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
>           at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>           - parking to wait for  <0x000000077b988460> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
>           at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:277)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.awaitLatch(NioEndpoint.java:1106)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.awaitReadLatch(NioEndpoint.java:1108)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:184)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:235)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:216)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1212)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1163)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:742)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$400(Http11InputBuffer.java:38)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1073)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.end(IdentityInputFilter.java:149)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.endRequest(Http11InputBuffer.java:632)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.endRequest(Http11Processor.java:1771)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1149)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           - locked <0x00000006ec5a53c0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Locked ownable synchronizers:
>           - <0x00000006e6f522b0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue ?